# consulta COUNT en dos campos misma tabla

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y le realizo la siguiente consulta :

```
SELECT COUNT(nivel) AS mat_estado, nivel, curso 
FROM mat_2021 
WHERE mat_estado='1' 
GROUP BY nivel
```

y me arroja lo que realmente necesito pero me omite algunos registros es decir en tercero medio me indica que tengo 2 registro pero no me los separa por la letra..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me temo que si le sigo agregando registros iguales me cuente igual. alguna solución con otra consulta mas especifica..??

quedo atento desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrupa por nivel y curso:

```
GROUP BY nivel, curso
```

Como en la consulta original solo se ha indicado que agrupe por nivel, efectivamente lo está haciendo. Pero del campo `curso` solo toma el valor de un registro del grupo.

Comment: estimado se agradece era la respuesta correcta..